# Подключение устройства к последовательному порту компьютера по RS422

Tags: linux, serial, передача-данных

Имеется промышленный компьютер с 4 последовательными портами и Ubuntu 22.04. (Модель материнской платы неизвестна) Требуется подключить устройство по протоколу RS422 (baudrate 460800, N 8, stop-bit 1, parity None, в общем все стандартно кроме скорости ). В BIOS имеется выбор режимов работы портов (RS232/485/422), был выбран соответсвующий режим - RS422.
Собственно в чем проблема: при чтении из порта получаю неверные символы (как при несоотвествии baudrate). Само устройство работает исправно (при подключении через USB преобразователь проблем нет).
вывод `dmesg | grep tty`

```
[    1.146160] 00:04: ttyS4 at I/O 0x240 (irq = 5, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    1.171954] 00:05: ttyS5 at I/O 0x248 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    1.197739] 00:06: ttyS6 at I/O 0x250 (irq = 6, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    1.223543] 00:07: ttyS7 at I/O 0x258 (irq = 10, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

Собственно `ttyS(4-7)` это те самые порты. Работают одинаково.
Не совсем понимаю что значит `base_baud`, и в каком отношени он находятится с `baudrate`, указанным при подключении к порту.
На всякий случай пробовал менять base_baud на 460800 через stty

```
sudo stty -F /dev/ttyS7 460800 cs8 -cstopb -parenb
```

на что получаю `unable to perform all requested operations` (с меньшими скоростями такой ошибки нет).

Все-таки установил через команду

```
sudo setserial /dev/ttyS7 baud_base 460800
```

Но результата нет.
Устройство обменивается бинарными пакетами, пакет должен начинаться с последовательности `0x1010`. Я даже визуалльно вижу, что там нет этой последовательности, ну и прикладной софт тоже не работает.

Comment: видимо контроллер не может более высокие скорости, если есть USB можно попробовать внешний, например `USB-RS422-WE-1800-BT`